# Angle between vector and plane

Tags: graphics, 3d

The angle between vector e.g. (2,3,5) and its projection on a plane (x-z) is different between its projection on a perpendicular plane(x-y) and the common axis (x-axis), I don't know why is that, can anyone explain that to me...

[image: 3d dimensions]

Answer (score 0):

The projection on the plane xz is the vector (2,0,5) and on the plane xy is (2,3,0). In any of the cases, the projection is given by the basis of the rectangular triangle where the original vector is the hipotenusa.